# How to aggregate and take the last value of one column at the same time in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to aggregate some data while at the same time taking the last (chronological) value of one of the columns...

I can achieve this with one CTE but wondered whether there is a shorter/more efficient way of doing this.

Let say I sell grocery and have both "Actual" Sales and "Estimate" Sales in my database.

I want to report on the total sales per product as well as returning whether the latest sales number is ACTUAL or ESTIMATE.

Here is my CTE solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SALES_DATA (SOMETHING         STRING NOT NULL
                                  , DATA_QUALITY      STRING NOT NULL
                                  , SALES             INTEGER
                                  , CREATED_ON        TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                                  );

INSERT INTO SALES_DATA(SOMETHING, DATA_QUALITY, SALES, CREATED_ON)
  VALUES('CARROTS', 'ESTIMATE',  23, '2021-03-09 13:09')
      , ('BANANAS', 'ACTUAL',     5, '2021-03-09 13:34')
      , ('CARROTS', 'ACTUAL',    12, '2021-03-09 14:09')
      , ('ORANGES', 'ACTUAL',    24, '2021-03-10 13:09')
      , ('BANANAS', 'ESTIMATE',  14, '2021-03-11 00:00')
  ;
  
-- At leaf level, just ensure all rows report the latest Data Quality instead of that of the row itself
WITH LATEST_DATA_QUALITY_ONLY
AS (
SELECT  SOMETHING
      , SALES
      , LAST_VALUE(DATA_QUALITY) OVER(PARTITION BY SOMETHING ORDER BY CREATED_ON) AS LATEST_DATA_QUALITY
  FROM SALES_DATA
)
SELECT SOMETHING
      ,MAX(LATEST_DATA_QUALITY) AS LATEST_DATA_QUALITY
      ,SUM(SALES) AS SALES
  FROM LATEST_DATA_QUALITY_ONLY 
  GROUP BY SOMETHING
  ORDER BY SOMETHING;
```

I expect this result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) to create array ordered by `CREATED_ON` and accessing first element:

```
SELECT SOMETHING
  ,(ARRAY_AGG(LATEST_DATA_QUALITY) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC))[0] 
    AS LATEST_DATA_QUALITY
  ,SUM(SALES) AS SALES   
FROM LATEST_DATA_QUALITY_ONLY    
GROUP BY SOMETHING   
ORDER BY SOMETHING;
```

This pattern tries to mimic [KEEP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238) clause.

Comment: I had to tweak a few details but it certainly does the job


SELECT SOMETHING
  ,(ARRAY_AGG(DATA_QUALITY) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC))[0] 
    AS LATEST_DATA_QUALITY
  ,SUM(SALES) AS SALES   
FROM SALES_DATA
GROUP BY SOMETHING   
ORDER BY SOMETHING;

Comment: @EricMamet I am happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the problem on it's head, and windowed SUM over the partition, and then only keep the last row via a QUALIFY:

```
SELECT something
    ,data_quality AS latest_data_quality
    ,SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY something ORDER BY created_on range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as sales
FROM sales_data
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY something ORDER BY created_on DESC) = 1
ORDER BY something, created_on;
```

Comment: Amazing stuff.
A bit more stuff for me to study! Thanks

Comment: I tried to accept both answers but it looks I can only select one...
Many thanks